# Pandas: Merge two data frames with different timestamps. Propagate missing values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

I have two dataframes that are on the same time period but with very different sampling frequencies. I would like still to merge those two with two simple rules.

Pick the value that is closer to the timestamps and then anything missing fill it in. Dates are not important just the timestamps.

I give an example of how the two dataframes look like

```
[140]:

data.index
[140]:
DatetimeIndex(['2019-02-08 07:53:26.380000', '2019-02-08 07:53:27.334000',
               '2019-02-08 07:53:27.653000', '2019-02-08 07:53:27.654000',
               '2019-02-08 07:53:27.655000', '2019-02-08 07:53:27.973000',
               '2019-02-08 07:53:27.974000', '2019-02-08 07:53:28.293000',
               '2019-02-08 07:53:28.304000', '2019-02-08 07:53:28.611000',
               ...
               '2019-02-08 14:41:03.128000', '2019-02-08 14:41:03.201000',
               '2019-02-08 14:41:03.260000', '2019-02-08 14:41:03.314000',
               '2019-02-08 14:41:03.429000', '2019-02-08 14:41:03.430000',
               '2019-02-08 14:41:03.748000', '2019-02-08 14:41:03.749000',
               '2019-02-08 14:41:03.752000', '2019-02-08 14:41:03.758000'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', name='Time', length=457631, freq=None)
[141]:

df.index
[141]:
Index(['07:53:26.380', '07:53:31.319', '07:53:31.825', '07:53:31.888',
       '07:53:31.889', '07:53:31.889', '07:53:31.988', '07:53:32.166',
       '07:53:32.287', '07:53:32.389',
       ...
       '14:40:43.759', '14:40:44.260', '14:40:44.761', '14:40:45.162',
       '14:40:45.662', '14:40:46.163', '14:40:46.664', '14:40:47.064',
       '14:40:47.064', '14:41:03.752'],
      dtype='object', name='Time', length=14641)
```

the **data** is the biggest dataframe and I would like to include the **df** dataframe as I described: Based on the closest matching time stamp and then propagate until the next one.

So far I have searched a lot online and I have found code that does merging.

For example:

```
merge=pd.merge(data,df, how='inner', left_index=True, right_index=True)

pd.concat([data,df], join='inner', axis=1)
```

None of those work (they return ofc empty data frame) since time matches do not match completely.

Your help and advice is more than appreciated.
Regards
Alex

Comment: Can't reproduce an answer since you didnt include example data. But take a look at [pandas.merge_asof](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.21/generated/pandas.merge_asof.html). A tip for the next time. If you include example data, you will more likely get better & faster answers

Answer (score 0):

You should use the merge_asof method in pandas, after converting the index of your second dataframe into a proper datetime type (is just time right now). Sample code below:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

#define the bigger dataframe
start = pd.Timestamp('2018-02-08 9:30:00')
end = pd.Timestamp('2018-02-08 15:45:00')
t = np.linspace(start.value, end.value, 100)
t = pd.to_datetime(t)
data=pd.DataFrame(index=t)
data['dummy_value1']=np.arange(len(data))

#define the smaller dataframe
start = pd.Timestamp('2018-02-08 14:30:00')
end = pd.Timestamp('2018-02-08 15:45:00')
t = np.linspace(start.value, end.value, 50)
t = pd.to_datetime(t)
df=pd.DataFrame(index=t)
df['dummy_value2']=10*np.arange(len(df))

#use merge_asof and verify the join has worked as expected by looking at last 10 rows
pd.merge_asof(data,df,left_index=True,right_index=True).tail(10)
```